# sorting nested dicts with lists in python

Tags: python, list, sorting, dictionary

I have a python dict that is like

```
flights = [
    {
        "Flight_Fare": [
            {"M": {"AvailableSets": "9+", "AdultBaseFare": "20"}},
            {"N": {"AvailableSets": "9+", "AdultBaseFare": "30"}},
        ]
    },
    {
        "Flight_Fare": [
            {"M": {"AvailableSets": "9+", "AdultBaseFare": "40"}},
            {"N": {"AvailableSets": "9+", "AdultBaseFare": "10"}},
        ]
    },
]
```

I would like to sort the '**Flights**' list based on the value of the object that has the cheapest price inside '**Flight_Fare**' under its '**AdultBaseFare**'.

So you can look at it like this,

each object inside '**Flights**' is for a flight and each flight has different classes (ex. one for Economy one for Bussiness) and each class has a different price. I want to sort the whole "**Flight**" list so that the first object inside the '**Flight**' list is the flight that has the cheapest price (doesn't matter if the other class in that flight is more expensive then the next flight)

I think the best way would be to first sort the '**Flight_Fare**' list of each Flight (so that each flight has its classes sorted based on the price) and then sort the '**Flight**' list based on the price of the first object in '**Flight_Fare**' in that flight.

can someone please help me with this?

Comment: Can you demonstrate *any* effort at solving this yourself?

Comment: Is the nested dict form a requirement?  I don't know what else you are doing with this data, but I think I'd make a `Flight_Fare` class which has all the attributes you'll need and the magic methods `__lt__` & `__gt__` (less than & greater than). This will allow natively sorting Flight_Fares.

Comment: Also, a predictable issue you might run into is that the fares as you have them now are strings. You'll want to convert those to a numeric datatype at some point

Comment: What result do you expect from your data?

Answer (score 0):

just make a function to get the cheapest adultbasefare for each flight and use it as the key for the `sorted` function

```
def get_cheapest(flight):
    fares = []
    for f in flight['Flight_Fare']:
        for key in f.keys():
            fares.append(f[key]['AdultBaseFare'])
    return float(min(fares))

flights = [
    {
        "Flight_Fare": [
            {"M": {"AvailableSets": "9+", "AdultBaseFare": "20"}},
            {"N": {"AvailableSets": "9+", "AdultBaseFare": "30"}},
        ]
    },
    {
        "Flight_Fare": [
            {"M": {"AvailableSets": "9+", "AdultBaseFare": "40"}},
            {"N": {"AvailableSets": "9+", "AdultBaseFare": "10"}},
        ]
    },
]

out = sorted(flights, key=lambda x: get_cheapest(x))
```